# Svelte losing bind when select options change

Tags: svelte

I'm working with Svelte and having problems with the bind using select. At first everything works fine and the `selected` variable value change to the only available option, but when I change the options (after 5 seconds in the example below), the bind is lost and the select value is no longer the  `selected` variable value.

```
<script>
    let questions = [{ id: 1, text: `Where did you go to school?` }]
    setTimeout(() => questions = [{ id: 1, text: `Where did you go to school?` }], 5000)
    let selected
</script>

<select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each questions as question}
        <option value={question}>
            {question.text}
        </option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I would just avoid binding to objects, which causes a reference check for the equality comparison. You also cannot send them with regular forms.

If you make the value the `id`, then there is no issue because both questions have an option with an *identical* ID.

```html
<option value={question.id}>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not that the 'binding is lost' (it isn't), it's that the value held by `selected` no longer matches one of the updated options. Object equality is set by *reference* not by *value*, meaning the `questions` set originally is a completely different array of different objects than the `questions` loaded 5 seconds in. Technically this means that `selected` holds a memory address reference that no longer points to any of the objects listed by the updated questions.

As H.B. correctly stated in his answer, binding to a scalar such as `question.id` instead works, provided the updated questions *do* contain an option with the selected ID.

[REPL proof](https://svelte.dev/repl/68d20c5cafee4d5884206fbb08ee30e3?version=3.55.1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new at Svelte myself, but I can try an answer here. I believe by replacing questions with a brand new array Svelte will reconstruct the option list, which is removing the selected attribute. It would be easy, however, to simply store the current value before making this change and assign it afterwards. Try something like this?

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const currentSelected = selected
  questions = [{ id: 1, text: `Where did you go to school?` }]
  selected = currentSelected
}, 5000)
```

Better yet, don't replace the questions array. Try surgically modifying it as you need with array methods (remember to initiate reaction afterwards with `questions = questions`). Then I'll bet it wouldn't lose the selected value unless that value was removed from the list.

Comment: Not working, the problem is not that the selected variable loose its value, the problem is that it lost the bind to the select DOM node.

Comment: Go with what H.B. said... I do think it has to do with using the object rather than a scalar value for the option values.